# Combining Dataframe plots into single figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to merge an arbitrary number of line charts into a single image, and while there are many, many questions about this sort of thing, none of them seem applicable to the code I'm working with.

Unlike a large number of answers, I don't want to have the separate graphs displayed side by side, or above one another, in a single output, but rather, combined together.

For all of these graphs the value of the "y_x" column would be the same, but the "yhat_y" produced during each loop would be different.

Adding `subplots = True` to the plot method of a dataframe seems to change the return type to something that is no longer compatible with the code `numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'`

```
    #ax = plt.subplot(111) doesnt seem to do anything
    for variable in range(max_num):

        forecast = get_forecast(variable)
        cmp1 = forecast.set_index("ds")[["yhat", "yhat_lower", "yhat_upper"]].join(
            both.set_index("ds")
        )

        e.augmented_error[variable]= sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error(
            cmp["y"].values, cmp1["yhat"].values
        )

        cmp2=cmp.merge(cmp1,on='ds')

        plot = cmp2[['y_x', 'yhat_y']].plot(title =e)
        fig1 = plot.get_figure()
        plot.set_title("prediction")
    
    plt.show()
    fig1.savefig('output.pdf', format="pdf")
    plt.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean "combined together"? Do you want all of the lines to be displayed on the same axes?

Comment: @DavidG yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to create a reusable `ax` handle outside the loop, then call `ax.plot` inside the loop:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots() # create reusable `fig` and `ax` handles

for variable in range(max_num):
    ...
    ax.plot(cmp2['y_x'], cmp2['yhat_y']) # use `ax.plot(cmp2...)` instead of `cmp2.plot()`

ax.set_title('predictions')
fig.savefig('output.pdf', format='pdf')
```